# AngularJS recognize swipe moves?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

Good Morning!

i have build a gui with material design and angularjs. if the sidenav is locked, on the main page are three tabs. the swipe moves on the tabs works with the md-swipe-content="true". i have build a swipe function for the sidenav, if the user swipes above the body (right), the menu swiped in.
But if the sidnav is locked and the user swipe right (to open the sidenav), the tab swiped and then the sidenav. Whats the right way to fix this problem?

i have seen some apps have a dragable sidenav from the left corner. Have someone a advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar some time ago. My solution was to create a directive that prevented a certain action to happen. I added that directive only to those components that needed a different behavior.

Comment: ok thanks, have you got a codepen snippet? Or a link to a short description :) I am a beginner @ angularjs + material design, thats the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it but basically it was listening for an event to happen and stopping its propagation